# best method to detect win32 services creation and deletion

Tags: c++, service

I'm trying to build a tool to monitor services using c++
I want to detect newly added services and the deletion of services without using EnumServicesStatusExW continuously and comparing the result array with the previous one

so I came to two functions SubscribeServiceChangeNotifications , NotifyServiceStatusChangeA

I don't know which is better to use , and I saw in the imports of ProcessHacker and didn't find any of them in the imports so I assume that ph uses a different method

Comment: If ProcessHacker doesn't use SCM monitoring functions, it might be using a virtual device driver instead to monitor system activity, similar to how SysInternals Process Monitor does. On the other hand, an app doesn't have to use its imports table to use DLL functions. It could load them dynamically at runtime instead, which would not show up in the imports table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SubscribeServiceChangeNotifications()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/subscribeservicechangenotifications) can detect services being added and deleted, using the `SC_EVENT_DATABASE_CHANGE` event type.  This method is available in Windows 8 and later.

[`NotifyServiceStatusChange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-notifyservicestatuschangew) can also detect services being added and deleted, using the `SERVICE_NOTIFY_CREATED` and `SERVICE_NOTIFY_DELETED` notify masks.  This method is available in Windows Vista and later.

Otherwise, you can monitor the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` Registry key for subkey changes, such as with [`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue) using the `REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_NAME` filter.  This method is available in Windows 2000 and later.

So, it is not so much about "which approach is best", it is more like "which approach is appropriate for the version of Windows my app is running on".  Your app could utilize all 3 approaches.  Using dynamic loading via `GetProcAddress()`, or your compiler's delay-load feature (if it has one), you can check for DLL function existence at runtime and act accordingly.  If `SubscribeServiceChangeNotifications()` exists then use it, otherwise if `NotifyServiceStatusChange()` exists then use it, otherwise if `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()` exists then use it.

Comment: very well , specially monitoring the registry key